# Why my code is not accepted in the contest?

Tags: python, string

```py
def is_the_same(palavraa):
    i=0
    j=1
    n=2
    while len(palavraa)!=0:
        if palavraa[0]==palavraa[i] and palavraa[1]==palavraa[j] and palavraa[2]==palavraa[n]:
            if i+3<len(palavraa):
                i=i+3
            elif j+3<len(palavraa):
                j=j+3
            elif n+3<len(palavraa):
                n=n+3
            else:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

x = input()   
t = int(x)

if t>=1 and t<=1000 :
    while t!=0:
        palavra = input()
        if len(palavra)>=3 and len(palavra)<=50:
            if palavra[0]=='Y' and palavra[1]=='e' and palavra[2]=='s':
                if is_the_same(palavra)==True:
                    print("YES")
                else:
                    print("NO")
            elif palavra[0]=='s' and palavra[1]=='Y' and palavra[2]=='e':
                if is_the_same(palavra)==True:
                    print("YES")
                else:
                    print("NO")
            elif palavra[0]=='e' and palavra[1]=='s' and palavra[2]=='Y':
                if is_the_same(palavra)==True:
                    print("YES")
                else:
                    print("NO")
            elif palavra[0]=='e' and palavra[1]=='s' and palavra[2]=='Y':
                if is_the_same(palavra)==True:
                    print("YES")
                else:
                    print("NO")
            else:
                print("NO")
        elif len(palavra)==2:
            if palavra[0]=='s' and palavra[1]=='Y':
                print("YES")
            elif palavra[0]=='e' and palavra[1]=='s':
                print("YES")
            else:
                print("NO")
        else: 
            print("NO")
        t=t-1
```

Did I write this code in order to solve the Sim-Sim problem? from codeforces Rond 834 Div 3 and when testing it with the inputs given by the site, they all gave the expected output but when I submitted the code it gave the wrong answer. Where did I go wrong?
The problem is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Couple quick tips - your question title should include the technical aspects of your problem, not your personal story. People tend to look for what they have expertise in when scrolling, and no one can tell if they'll be able to help when a question title reads like "Can you help me with this?". Also, images are generally discouraged; links can break, and the text can't be copy-and-pasted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_the_same(palavraa):
i=0
j=1
n=2
while len(palavraa)!=0:
    if palavraa[0]==palavraa[i] and palavraa[1]==palavraa[j] and palavraa[2]==palavraa[n]:
        if i+3<len(palavraa):
            i=i+3
        elif j+3<len(palavraa):
            j=j+3
        elif n+3<len(palavraa):
            n=n+3
        else:
            break
    else:
        return False
return True
```

This block of code is very strange. After staring at it for a while I understand what it's trying to do, but you're going about it in a very confusing way. First, the condition on your while statement `len(palavraa)!=0` isn't modified by anything inside the loop - this makes it very difficult to read. Second, the `if`/`elif` structure means that you'll only be updating one of the three variables per loop iteration, when really, you want to want to be doing all three. This would be much simpler as:

```
i = 0
while(i + 3 < len(palvara)):
   if (palvara[i] != palvara[i+3]):
     return False
   i = i + 1
return True
```

Your basic algorithm seems to be to check if the string is a repition of the same three characters, and then see if the first three characters are "Y", "e" and "s" rotated in any manner. Right?

Moving on, you repeat this clause:

```
        elif palavra[0]=='e' and palavra[1]=='s' and palavra[2]=='Y':
            if is_the_same(palavra)==True:
                print("YES")
            else:
                print("NO")
```

Finally, you don't cover all of the shorter clauses - you miss one of the 2-length strings, and have nothing for length 1.

By the way, in general coding contests will run some number of public tests, then some number of hidden tests. You'll be shown what went wrong if you fail a public test, but if you fail a hidden test it will be up to you to figure out what went wrong by reviewing your code and the problem statement.